# How to prove this integral is divergent: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Show that this following integral is divergent (or diverges, if you prefer)
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dx}{\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}}$$

I know that $x=0,1$ are singularities of the function and I want use the following well-known inequality:
$$\ln{(1+x)}<x, \,\text{whenever $x>-1$}.
$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}}>\dfrac{1}{-x\ln{x}}>0$$
since
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x\ln{x}}=\ln{\ln{x}}|_{0}^{1}=+\infty$$

Are there any other methods I could use?

Answer (score 6):

Note the simple fact the integrand is positive and

$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x\ln{x}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{x}{\log(1-x)}}_{\large\text{near 0 it behaves like $-1$}}dx\longrightarrow \infty$$

**Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $0 < x \leqslant 1$,

$$x \leqslant -\ln(1-x) \leqslant \frac{x}{1-x},$$

and

$$\frac{1}{\ln x\ln(1-x)}= \frac{1}{[-\ln x ][-\ln(1-x)]} \leqslant \frac1{-x\ln x.}$$

So your comparison is not correct.

However, for $0 < x < 1/2$

$$\frac{1}{\ln x\ln(1-x)} \geqslant \frac{x-1}{x\ln x} \geqslant \frac{-1}{2x\ln x},$$

and the integral of $1/ (2x\ln x) $ over $[0,1/2]$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you can decompose the integrand into partial fractions for the form
$$\frac{f(x)}{\ln x}+\frac{g(x)}{\ln(1-x)}$$
or, equivalently,
$$f(x)\ln(1-x)+g(x)\ln x=1$$
Set $f$ to a relatively simple function, which in this case might be $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$, then you have
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x\ln x}$$
So the integral is equivalent to
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x\ln x}+\int_0^1\frac{g(x)}{\ln(1-x)}~dx$$
The first integral diverges, so the original integral must diverge as well.

Comment: I don't follow your last line. That logic would imply that because $\int_0^1\frac1x\,dx$ is divergent, then so is $\int_0^1\left(\frac1x-\frac1x\right)\,dx$, which is not true.

Comment: Fair point, but is $\frac{g(x)}{\ln(1-x)}=-\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ ?

Comment: I think you missed my point. I'm not suggesting that your two integrands cancel out like $\frac1x$ and ${-\frac1x}$ do. I'm just suggesting that "The first integral diverges, so the original integral must diverge as well" is not correct logic. If the original integral were $\int_0^1\left(\frac1x-\frac1x\right)dx$, then you would have it written as $\int_0^1\frac1xdx+\int_0^1\frac{-1}{x}dx$, and say that "the first integral diverges, so the original integral must diverge as well." And yet it is clear that the original integral converges in that example.

Comment: What alex.jordan means (and he never mentions *explicitely*), is that the other function may cancel the divergence of the other one, even without entirely canceling it.

Comment: If the first integral is divergent AND the second one is convergent then he can claim that their sum is divergent, but he do not know what about the second one, that is why the logic behind is not correct.

Comment: @alex.jordan Oh I see, sorry for the erroneous reasoning. I guess I was approaching this from a Calc 2 mindset... Everyone else's contribution seems to be significantly more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete proof that the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{%
\ln x\ln (1-x)}$ diverges.

Let $a\in \left( 0,1/2\right) .$ The function $\frac{x}{\ln (1-x)}$ is
continuous over $\left[ a,\frac{1}{2}\right] ,$ and the function $\frac{1}{%
x\ln x}$ is of one sign in $\left[ a,\frac{1}{2}\right] ,$ then by the first
mean value theorem for integration, it follows that there exists $%
t_{0}=t_{0}(a)\in \left[ a,\frac{1}{2}\right] $ such that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)} &=&\int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{x}{\ln (1-x)}%
\frac{dx}{x\ln x} \\
&=&\frac{t_{0}(a)}{\ln (1-t_{0}(a))}\int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\ln x},\ \text{
for all}\ a\in \left( 0,1/2\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
since the function $\frac{t}{\ln (1-t)}$ is increasing in $\left(
0,1/2\right) $ then 
$$
\frac{t_{0}(a)}{\ln (1-t_{0}(a))}\leq \frac{1/2}{\ln \left( 1-(1/2)\right) }<0, \text{
for all}\ a\in \left( 0,1/2\right) 
$$
let $M=-\frac{1/2}{\ln (1-1/2)}= \frac{1}{2\ln 2}>0.$ Then $\text{
for all}\ a \in \left( 0,1/2\right) ,$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\vert \int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}\right\vert  &=&\left\vert 
\frac{t_{0}(a)}{\ln (1-t_{0}(a))}\right\vert \left\vert \int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{%
dx}{x\ln x}\right\vert  \\
&\geq &M\left\vert \int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\right\vert ,\ \text{for
all }a\in \left( 0,1/2\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

passing to the limit as $a$ tends to $0^{+}$ leads to
$$
\left\vert \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}\right\vert \geq
M\left\vert \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\right\vert 
$$
Since $\left\vert \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\right\vert =+\infty $ then
the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}=+\infty .$
Now note that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}$ satisfies $%
f(1-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)} &=&\lim_{a\rightarrow
0^{+}}\int_{1/2}^{1-a}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)} \\
&=&\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{a}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)} \\
&=&\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}=+\infty .
\end{eqnarray*}
Since BOTH integrals $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}$ and $%
\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}$ are $+\infty $ then their the
integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\ln x\ln (1-x)}$ is also $+\infty$ .

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\quad x \equiv \expo{-t}\ \imp\ t = -\ln\pars{x}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}}&=
> \int_{\infty}^{0}{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t \over -t\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-t}}}
> =-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-t}}}\,\dd t
> \end{align}

When $\ds{t\ \ggg 0}$ the integrand behaves as $\ds{1 \over t}$ such the integral diverges '$\tt logarithmically$' at the upper limit.

> When $\ds{t\ \gtrsim 0}$ the integrand behaves as $\ds{-\,{1 \over t\ln\pars{t}}}$ such the integral diverges as $\ds{\ln\pars{-\ln\pars{t}}}$ at the
>   $\tt\mbox{lower limit}$.

Moreover, those divergences $\tt\mbox{don't cancel each other}$, such that the original integral $\sf diverges{\rm\mbox{ !!!}}$.